# Selenium IDE custom function with Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, selenium

I have a custom selenium function that is posting data via an Ajax call (PHP script to open file). Whats throwing me is if i run the code in the browser console it works but when i run the function through selenium IDE it doesnt' post the data.

**PHP**

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$report = $_POST['report'];

$report_file = fopen("report.txt", "w");
fwrite($report_file, $report);
fclose($report_file);
```

**Selenium function**

```
Selenium.prototype.doSaveCopyPaste = function(locator) {
 $ = _getGlobalVar('jQuery');
 var text = $(locator).text();

 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('report', text);

 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://copypaste.test',
   data: formData,
   dataType: 'text',
   processData: false, 
   contentType: false,
     success: function(){ 
      alert('Success'); 
     },
     error: function() {
      alert('failed');
     } 
 });
}
```

**Selenium IDE**

```
command: saveCopyPaste  Target: #plain-report  Value:
```

The test goes green as if to indicate it has passed but the file isn't created..

Where as if i do this in the browser console (firefox) the file is created

```
 var text = $('#plain-report').text();

 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('report', text);

 var ajax = $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://copypaste.test',
   data: formData,
   dataType: 'text',
   processData: false, 
   contentType: false,
     success: function(){ 
      alert('Success'); 
     },
     error: function() {
      alert('failed');
     } 
 });
```

Is there any reason why using this as a custom function is causing the file not to be created through the selenium test?

I'm a bit stumped as this should be working

EDIT

A little more debugging has found that the POST isn't' even happening when trying to do it through selenium

Within the net tab when firing the call within the console i get

```
POST  http://copypaste.test/
```

but when running through selenium there is nothing in the net tab

the output of `console.log(ajax)` returns

```
[object Object]
```

another thought is would the fact that prototype.js and jquery are being used conflict with this call, i have tried the noConflict(); method though and that did no make a difference.

Thanks

Comment: any error? are all of the libraries loaded in the IDE?

Comment: all libraries are loaded, same versions of jQuery are being used.. no error. though would be interested in getting a log of formData from the ajax call... how would i access that?